# Limit of a sequence with real and natural number variables

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Currently learning about limits and I'd like to check out if I calculated that all correctly:

**number 1: SOLVED**

> $$a_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{(n^2+1)}$$
>
> This was (hopefully) very simple, sadly I stil lack the correct expressions to >!explain it. So I divide by $n_2$:
>
> **EDITED Nr. 1 AFTER POSTS OF OTHER USERS**
> So sequence a converges to 1: $$\lim_{n \to \infty }a_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{(n^2+1)} =\frac{1}{1}=1$$

**number 2: UNSOLVED** $$a_n=\frac{c_2n^2+c_1n+c_0}{b_2n^2+b_1n+b_0} \text{with $c_1,c_2,c_3 \in \Bbb{R} \land b_1,b_2,b_3 \in \Bbb{R}_{>0}$}$$
Intuitively I would say this goes towards infinity, so I don't believe it converges. Yet, I find myself having difficulties calculating that.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty }a_n=\frac{c_2n^2+c_1n+c_0}{b_2n^2+b_1n+b_0}$$

Divide by $n^2$:

$$\dfrac{c_2+\dfrac{c_1}{n}+\dfrac{c_0}{n^2}}{b_2+\dfrac{b_1}{n}+\dfrac{b_0}{n^2}}=\dfrac{c_2}{b_2}$$

So even though $b_0$ is positive (by definition), we can not say that the sequence converges for any specific number..? (If I put in $\infty$ for $c_2$ into the sequence it returns $\infty$, if I put it into  $c_3$ it returns $-\infty$, if I put it into both result is undefined? or is it infinity again?)

**number 3: SOLVED**

> $$a_n= \frac{13n^6-27}{26n^5\sqrt{n}+39\sqrt{n}}$$
>
> So here I can **divide by $n^6$** (I will skip some parts to not clutter up my question any more, everything $\dfrac{1}{n^x}$ and $\sqrt(n)$ turns to 0:
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty }a_n= \frac{13-0}{\dfrac{26n^{5+0,5}}{n^6}+0} = \frac{13}{\dfrac{26}{n^{0,5}}} = \frac{13}{0} = \infty $$
>
> So again it doesn't have a limit..? easier solution from: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2791582/560190

Comment: $$\frac{(\frac{1}{n^2})(n^2+n)}{(\frac{1}{n^2})(n^2+1)} = ?$$

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Hint: these limits can be easily evaluated exploiting the "hierarchy of infinity" (for polynomials, higher order means it goes to infinity "faster").

Comment: @user1994928  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Hey, I would, but op isn't solved. number 2 is still unsolved though.

Answer (score 1):

For number 1 we have

$$a_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{(n^2+1)}=\frac{(1+1/n)}{(1+1/n^2)}
$$

and for number 3

$$a_n= \frac{13n^6-27}{26n^5\sqrt{n}+39\sqrt{n}}=\frac{n^6}{n^5\sqrt{n}}\cdot\frac{13-27/n^6}{26+39/n^5}
$$

Comment: Yes, I see my mistake in number 1, seems like a "brainfart" from my side, thanks for pointing it out. 

For n.3(, can I just "remove" the constants without explaining why? I understand that it is possible and why it is possible, but I thought it could be a sign of "bad form" to just skip writing them down... Or is it not? That would definitely be helpful then.). I don't see where your solution would lead me to. The right factor would become 0,5 (?) because it only leaves 13/26. The right factor turns into 1/0..? So my answer is correct, but the way that got me there was wrong?

Comment: @user1994928 You solution is not wrong but it is a little bit confusing to me. Collectin $n^6$ form the numerator and $n^5\sqrt n$ form teh denominator we obtain a limit in teh form $\infty \cdot 13/26=\infty$.

Comment: Ok, thanks.

Did me splitting up the roots so I can divide them as a single factor and adding the left root to the $n^5$ confuse you?